# running matlab command line in screen -- can't type after reattaching

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen, matlab

I'm logging in via ssh to a more powerful computer, on this I start a screen session with `screen -S mine` and then open a matlab command line via `matlab -nodesktop -nodplash` and then run within matlab a long running script. After detaching from the screen and logging out from the computer the script is running using all the CPU power.

Now if I wait quite a while (the matlab skripkt will in total need like 6-7 hours and I don't want to save the matlab session since I would need to load all 15GB to RAM again) and try to reattach to the screen this at first seeems to work.

I get my screen `mine` back and see the matlab command line, which finished the job, but I can't type anything within the matlab command line? Why is this? I now can't continue and killed it. (I noticed using htop that matlab at first used 100% CPU, in the end still 100% were used but a major part was colored red so used for kernel tasks..)

Comment: What you do you mean precisely by "can't type anything within the matlab command line"? When you type letters, they don't show up (i.e. aren't echoed) where you expect? Do control sequences like clear-screen (^L) work? How about screen's control sequences, e.g. C-a C-c to create a new window?

Comment: Also, perhaps try an `strace` to see what matlab's doing?

Comment: You can try "blindly" typing `reset` and Enter. This often helps to get the console back to a working state.